# How to show a decrementing counter in a such a way that it should resembles with timer starting from 00:00 to nn:nn?

Tags: android, timer

I have a an activity in which on the title bar i have to show the decrementing counter in time format mm:ss (i.e starting from 00:00 to nn:nn). It should start as soon onCreate method is triggerd.

Comment: Have a look at a class called CountDownTimer

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks Jeff. Got a simple and better answer ...... 


//code....
 m_handler = new Handler();
        m_handlerTask = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String min = "00";
                String sec = "00";

                if (((timeCount / 60) + "").length() == 1) {
                    min = "0" + (timeCount / 60);
                } else {
                    min = (timeCount / 60) + "";
                }


                //txtMinutes.setText(""+timeCount);
                if (((timeCount % 60) + "").length() == 1) {
                    sec = "0" + (timeCount % 60);
                } else {
                    sec = (timeCount % 60) + "";
                }


                txtMinutes.setText(min + ":" + sec);
                timeCount++;
            m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
            }
        };
        m_handlerTask.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the code much further using this:

```
txtMinutes.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",(int)(timeCount/60) ,(int)(timeCount%60)));
```

Hope this helps!